# Why we need MCH bone?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints

### Below in the pictures I have clarified the question and made it concrete.
[Simple Rig Example Blender File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j0ZGVFLtJRgiVz2GAIDIZdwD9h6d_ncV?usp=sharing) - for more details

P.S. - setting of our rig - all axes of bones perfectly aligned. All constrains have World Space orientation. Constraint "Copy location" has offset - i.e. Head/Tail setted to 1.000.

I see in tutors about rig this decition with MCH bone for creating switchable rotational inheritance on some bone chains. I don't understand when a MCH bone is needed, and when it is possible to do without it. [PierrickPicaut](https://www.youtube.com/c/PierrickPicaut_P2DESIGN/videos)  - always use MCH bones when want to create swtchable filter for some transform channel inheritance or just isolate some transform channels from copying by after bone.

---

Why we can't just unparent our Targer bone and use contrains to get full control under transform channels that parent bone transfer chiled bone ( i.e. Target bone ).

[image: Title]
[image: Mech1]
[image: Mech2]
[image: ?]
[image: Like this]
[image: Finish]

Comment: What you're asking about is why a *specific* bone needs to be present.  In order to answer that question, we need more details (what space do the constraints operate in?  Are they set to offset?  What are the bones' axes and positions?), details that would be communicated very quickly and easily by sharing a file demonstrating the 3 bones (and hopefully, only those 3 bones.)  Is it possible that bone is unnecessary?  Yes, it is; sometimes people don't always think things through perfectly, and sometimes structures exist only because it simplifies understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the post, added a file with an example.

Comment: If it's simple rig, you probably don't need anything complicated and it's redundant. When you start to separate rotations, lock different axis individually or do more complex blends, these extra bones come handy. Take a look at this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41591/7777, different issue but serves as example when extra bones help. Some people add bones like these from habit even where they are not immediately needed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a pretty simple setup.  In this case, the division into Source (control)-> MCH (mechanism) ->TGT (deform) is not necessary.  It looks more like a lesson about how rigs *can* be divided into multiple layers like this, which is often necessary, even if it's not necessary here.

Answer (score -1):

My theory to answer the question  - which problem MCH solve in this situation.

[image: Highlight]
[image: Finish]
[image: Finish2]

Comment: "Local with parent can become buggy very fast as the chain gets longer. Use it orientation mode at your own risk" - Pierrick Picaut said at comment in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ9WTFeDhJM